# How do I run a ruby script, that I put in my /lib/tasks/ directory in my Rails app, once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Eventually I would like to get to setting it up as a Rake task and do a cron job, but for right now...all I want to do is take my ruby script that used to work as a standalone script and have it work within my Rails app.

I renamed the file to be `.rake` instead of `.rb` and tried doing `rake my_script` at the command-line, but that gave me this error message:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'my_script'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I run this script within my Rails environment?

This is the first time I am doing something like this, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between a runner and a rake task is : runner would boot rails while rake task doesn't (you can tell it to do so).

Since rake can do both (boot/no boot), there's no concept of runner in rails-3 anymore.

So, create a rake task: `whatever_name.rake`

Example:

```
desc "This task does awesome stuff"
  task :do_awesome_stuff do
  awesome_method
end

def awesome_method
  #put your ruby code here
end
```

Now from your command prompt, type `rake do_awesome_stuff` to execute this rake task.

To make it boot Rails, change task definition to this:

```
task :do_awesome_stuff => :environment do
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is rails runner. I know in Rails 2.3.x you'd do

```
ruby script/runner <your file>
```

In Rails 3 it might be slightly different.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner

Comment: Would I then name it `my_script.rb`? Or `my_script.rake`?

Comment: Yep, name it my_script.rb. Runner will run any ruby file.